# Android achartengine set x axes step

Tags: android

I'm using achartengine to display a line chart. The x axis shows the number of times an advert has been viewed so it doesn't make sense to have y axis labels that are not whole numbers. The xaxis numbers comes like 0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5 but i want to display like 1,2,3,4.
Is there any way to set the minimum step of the axis labels to 1 or tell it to only show whole number axis labels.

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int m=0;m<maximum_possible_value;m++){
    mRenderer.addXTextLabel(m, Integer.toString(m));
}
mRenderer.setXLabels(0);
mRenderer.setShowCustomTextGrid(true);
```

This will set all the X axis labels to be whole number values. maximum_possible_value is the maximum possible value in the x axis.